# Should "b" be capitalized in Dick's burger/burgers?

Tags: american-english, capitalization

As **Dick's Drive-In** is a fast food restaurant company and if someone refers to a particular fast food item say "burger". Do we capitalize "b" when someone says Dick's burger? In short when someone refers to particular fast food items of a branded name, should we capitalize that particular food item?

Comment: Only if it is a name: Dick's Burgers.

Comment: This seems like a very basic question, one that can be answered by simply googling it. Did you try solving your problem by searching similar questions here in ELL? Please show your research.

Comment: (1) *Dick's burgers*: the name of the restaurant is Dick's (or Dick). (2) *Dick's Burgers*: the name of the restaurant is Dick's Burgers. In fact, this could lead to some interesting phrasing if you're not careful with choosing your words. The following is fairly normal: *I ate a burger from Dick's Burgers*. But while the following is grammatical, it's strange: *I ate a Dick's Burgers burger*.

Answer (score 1):

**Dick's burgers** deserve the same treatment as Dick's dog or Dick's car.

If you are simply referring to burgers supplied by Dick, as in : **We are having some of Dick's burgers for lunch**, you don't capitalise - any more than you would if you said: **We are having burgers that we obtained from Dick's**.

But if you are referring to the name of the outlet, as in: **We have got supplies from Dick's Burgers**, then you do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So based on your answer, I think we should capitalize B in a sentence like this: "where is the nearest Dick's Burgers"? As here it is referring to the outlet.

Comment: As you say. It's the name.